# JVM crashes using underline '_' as part of SNI server name

Tags: java, openssl, netty, sni, boringssl

I'm using `Netty 4.1.14.Final` for my application's framework. I want to implement that the server can check the SNI information when the clients request using `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static`.

But my application crashes once as I specify the `-servername` as `svc.v1`, and I got this message:

```
java: ../ssl/handshake_server.c:541: negotiate_version: Assertion `!ssl->s3->have_version' failed.
```

with the OpenSSL command:

```
openssl s_client -cert service.crt -key service.key -CAfile root_ca.pem -connect 127.0.0.1:8080 -servername svc.v1_1
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 210 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1532336403
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

However, it works well if I specify the `-servername` as `svc.v1`, without the underline `_`.

Here is my Netty server implementation:

```
// define ssl provider
private static final SslProvider SSL_PROVIDER = SslProvider.OPENSSL;

// factory method for creating ssl context
public SslContext serverCtx(InputStream certificate, InputStream privateKey) {
        try {
            return SslContextBuilder.forServer(certificate, privateKey)
                                    .sslProvider(SSL_PROVIDER)                                         
                                    .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)
                               .trustManager(TwoWayTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to create ssl context", e);
        }
}

// SNI Matcher implementation
@Slf4j
public class MySNIMatcher extends SNIMatcher {

    private final byte[] hostIdentifier;

    public MySNIMatcher(Identifier hostIdentifier) {
        super(0);
        this.hostIdentifier = hostIdentifier.idDistKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(SNIServerName sniServerName) {
        return Arrays.equals(sniServerName.getEncoded(), hostIdentifier);
    }
}

// Netty bootstrap
bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        if (conf.logEnable())
            pipeline.addLast("logging", new LoggingHandler());

        if (conf.sslEnable()) {
            // conf.sslCtx() will actually use serverCtx() to create context
            SSLEngine engine = conf.sslCtx().newEngine(ch.alloc());
            SSLParameters s = engine.getSSLParameters();
            s.setSNIMatchers(new MySNIMatcher(...));
            s.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
            engine.setSSLParameters(s);
            pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine, true));
        }

        codec(pipeline);

        int idleTimeout = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(conf.idleTimeout());
        if (0 < idleTimeout)
            pipeline.addLast("idle", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, idleTimeout));

        pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);
    }                  
})
```

Version: 
netty -> 4.1.14.Final
netty-tcnative-boringssl-static -> 2.0.5.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hostnames are not allowed to contain an underscore character, per the original RFC 952, and modified by RFC 1123.  The following is from the Wikipedia page for [Hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_hostnames).

> The Internet standards (Requests for Comments) for protocols mandate that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the minus sign ('-'). The original specification of hostnames in [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952), mandated that labels could not start with a digit or with a minus sign, and must not end with a minus sign. However, a subsequent specification ([RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123)) permitted hostname labels to start with digits. No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are permitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But is it the same meaning between the ```-servername``` parameter  and ```Hostnames```?

Comment: Or in my example above, the ```Hostname``` is ```127.0.0.1``` and also is ```svc.v1_0```?

Comment: And is there any ways to avoid JVM crash when the hostname is illegal? Thanks

Comment: It appears the crash is likely a bug, it should produce a meaningful exception and not crash.